# Remove Cancel Button From Azure AD B2C Policy Pages

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, mobile-application, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated Azure AD B2C on my Android App using `MSAL`, and created policy for `SignUpSignIn` and received the access token once the authentication is successful. The  `signUp` default page provided by azure have a `CANCEL` button in the Page. so how can i hide or remove the `CANCEL` button from the  `UI` element?

Answer (score 3):

See the self asserted technical profile reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata

Configure the setting.showCancelButton metadata item to false.

Comment: Where should i put the `setting.showCancelButton`  ? is it supposed to be done on azure portal or from  mobile app code?

Comment: You must be using a User Flow, my answer is in reference for Custom Policy. The only option in User Flow is to use CSS to hide the Cancel button.